# Resize a UITableView iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, resize, tableview, detailview

I have a main menu. Where we can find some buttons to different Function.
I used ModalTransition to switch between views, so I didn't use NavController.
One function is a TableView, then detailview.

On the .xib, I can't move the TableView, and when I'm on my simulator on my tableview, I can't go back, because the tableview take all the screen.
I'd like to Resize the tableview to add a Navigation bar and custom my own button.
How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `UITableView` frame yourself -

```
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 416.0, 320.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

User UiTableView **frame** property to achieve your goal

Declare the tableview as IBOutlet

**.h**

```
interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize myTableView;
```

Then open .Xib and **connect myTableView** with you .Xib table

Then **Resize the table view**

```
self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200); // assign you frame here
```

or Try to add the UITable **through programatically**..Take a look the below code

```
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
    [self.view addSubview:tableView]; 
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your proposition and Vakul's method and I have the same problem, the Tableview doesn't move ...

Comment: Try to add the UITable through programatically..Take a look this code http://pastebin.com/93W2v116   i have edited my answer